# Is it possible to call a Node JS script from Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm using Node JS with express on a server. I am trying to use Javascript to call my node js script every five minutes. I cannot find a way to do this anywhere online..is this even possible? Or is there a better way to do this with my Express server?

Comment: Read up on AJAX and/or WebSockets.

Comment: Can I ask why you have to call it every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to run code *for each open client* every five minutes, make an [AJAX (HTTP) request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) from a [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) callback:

```
// client-side JS
setInterval(function makeIntervalRequest() {
  // `fetch` is a built-in HTTP request function. 
  // It's in recent browsers. You could use a library like jQuery's $.ajax 
  //  or the built-in XMLHttpRequest for older browsers.
  // "/ping" is the URL to request.
  fetch("/ping");
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```

Because the browser controls this code, it will be run once for each client. If 6 users have your page open, you'll get 6 requests over a 5 minute window.

If you need to run code on the server *once* every five minutes, use `setInterval` right in your server code:

```
// server-side JS
setInterval(function runScheduledAction() {
  doTheScheduledAction();
}, 5 * 60 * 1000);
```